# C# programming Using objects, data fields & Arrays

Tags: c#, arrays

How do I create an array with objects, prompt the user for data for each object? I have some code but getting some errors with nonexistent "names"

```
//Main 
public class TaxPayerDemo
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Taxpayer[] t = new Taxpayer[10];
        int x;
        for (x = 0; x < t.Length; ++x)
        {
            t[x] = new Taxpayer(SSN, Gross);
            Console.WriteLine("Type your SSN");
            t.SSN = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Please enter your income");
            t.Gross = Convert.ToString(Console.ReadLine());


        }
    }
    class Taxpayer
    {

        private string ssn;
        private double gross; 
        private double tax;


        public string SSN
        {
            get
            {
                return ssn;

            }
            set
            {
                CalcTax();
            }
        }
        public double Gross
        {
            get
            {
                return gross;

            }
            set
            {
                CalcTax();
            }
        }

        private void CalcTax()
        {
            if (tax < 30000)
            {
                tax = .15 * Gross;
            }
            else
                if (tax > 30000)
                {
                    tax = .28 * Gross;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

ERRORS:

> Error 4    'System.Array' does not contain a definition for
>   'Gross' and no extension method 'Gross' accepting a first argument of
>   type 'System.Array' could be found (are you missing a using directive
>   or an assembly
>   reference?)   C:\homework\300\ConsoleApplication11\ConsoleApplication1\Class1.cs  20  19  ConsoleApplication1
>
> Error 3   'System.Array' does not contain a definition for 'SSN' and no
>   extension method 'SSN' accepting a first argument of type
>   'System.Array' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an
>   assembly
>   reference?)   C:\homework\300\ConsoleApplication11\ConsoleApplication1\Class1.cs  18  19  ConsoleApplication1
>
> Error 2   The name 'Gross' does not exist in the current
>   context   C:\homework\300\ConsoleApplication11\ConsoleApplication1\Class1.cs  16  42  ConsoleApplication1
>
> Error 1   The name 'SSN' does not exist in the current
>   context   C:\homework\300\ConsoleApplication11\ConsoleApplication1\Class1.cs  16  37  ConsoleApplication1

Comment: Can you post your code?

Comment: Could you post the code you are having problems with?

Comment: Give him or her a chance to paste some code and improve the question before the down votes.

Comment: @DjavanN.: Please edit your question. Do not post code chunks into comments.

Comment: SOrry I have a few project running posted the wrong one

Comment: Can you please post the actual error as well?

Comment: I know how to create the array, my problem is getting the data and calculations for the fields gross, tax, and ssn in to the main then accepting user input for them

Comment: @DjavanN.: Check out my latest edit below. I think it will give you everything you need and then some. Just please study it. Don't just copy and paste.

Comment: Your SSN and Gross setter methods are wrong. SSN setter should be set { ssn = value; } & Gross setter should be set { gross = value; }

Comment: @failedprogramming: Or better yet, auto properties can be used to limit errors like those.

Comment: @PaulSasik You are absolutely correct! Well unless he's not targetting .NET Framework 3.0 or greater.

Comment: @failedprogramming: True. And there are those out there but it's rare. Also reversing out of auto properties is pretty simple.

Comment: I am studying for a final, so I am trying to add comments that make sense. I want to be able to do this comfortably one day which is why i joined this forum not just for quick answers. So thank you everyone

Comment: @DjavanN.: While here, please read the FAQ. StackOverflow is no ordinary forum. The way it works is unique.

Answer (score 1):

Errors 1 and 2 are caused by this line of code

```
t[x] = new Taxpayer(SSN, Gross);
```

Here, `SSN` and `Gross` are not variables within the function or members of the `TaxPayerDemo` class.

Errors 3 and 4 come from this section of code:

```
t.SSN = Console.ReadLine();
Console.WriteLine("Please enter your income");
t.Gross = Convert.ToString(Console.ReadLine());
```

You are attempting to access `SSN` and `Gross` as though they were properties of the array itself, but they are actually properties of its elements.

Next you have an issue because `Gross` is of type `double`, but `Convert.ToString` returns a `string`. You must parse the console input as a `double` to assign it to your property.

It should read:

```
t[x] = new Taxpayer();
...
t[x].SSN = Console.ReadLine();
Console.WriteLine("Please enter your income");
t[x].Gross = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
```

As **Paul Sasik** answer points out, there is another in the `CalcTax` method. Your implementation has

```
if (tax < 30000)
...
else if (tax > 30000)
```

This means that there is a case when `tax == 30000` in which the `tax` would not be calculated at all. Secondly, I'm wondering why you're trying to calculate `tax` using `tax`. The value may change after you call it the first time. I think you mean to test `Gross` instead. I'd recommend something like this:

```
var rate = (this.Gross < 30000) ? 0.15 : 0.28;
this.tax = rate * this.Gross
```

Comment: Sorry guys, my first post and first C# course. Hopefully I can improve my activity so I can get the help I'm looking for in the best way.

Comment: @pswg: Gross is a double. You cannot assign a string to it.

Comment: I corrected that error, it should read ToDouble, thanks

Comment: +1 Nice explanations but there are more issues lurking. Take a look at the CalcTax function...

Comment: @PaulSasik +1 for completeness :)

Comment: How do I take the calculations of Tax from CalcTax() and call them to the main?

Answer (score 1):

There were a number of issues. Try this: (Note that I reduced the array size to 2 for easier testing.)

```
using System;

public class TaxPayerDemo
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Taxpayer[] t = new Taxpayer[2];
        int x;
        for (x = 0; x < t.Length; ++x)
        {
            t[x] = new Taxpayer();//SSN, Gross);
            Console.WriteLine("Type your SSN");
            t[x].SSN = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Please enter your income");
            t[x].Gross = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        }

        for (x = 0; x < t.Length; ++x)
        {
                            t[x].CalcTax();
            Console.WriteLine(t[x].SSN + " " + t[x].Gross + " " + t[x].Tax);
        }

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}

class Taxpayer
{
    public double Tax { get; set; }
    public string SSN { get; set; }
    public double Gross { get; set; }

    public void CalcTax()
    {
        if (Gross < 30000)
        {
            Tax = .15 * Gross;
        }
        else if (Gross >= 30000)
        {
            Tax = .28 * Gross;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: See the latest edits. It should ve `t[x].Gross` because you are taking an object from the array by index. t.Gross is meaningless.

Comment: t is an array, it does not have a Gross property. t[x] is the xth Taxpayer in the array and has a Gross property. But I'm not sure how you are gonna accept inputs in a WriteLine statement

Comment: I see you used the auto-implementation feature. I originally used it but wasn't sure.

Comment: @DjavanN.: Always use auto-properties unless you need custom logic in the getters/setters. It cleans up the code a lot and prevents mistakes.

Comment: How do I  take the calculations of Tax from CalcTax() and call them to the main?

Comment: @DjavanN. OK. Made the change... The method has to be public and called from the 2nd for loop to perform the calculation.